# Performance of Initialization from Different Type

Tags: c++, c, optimization, initialization, type-conversion

I'm porting some code, and the original author was evidently quite concerned with squeezing as much performance as possible out of the code.

Throughout (and there's *hundreds* of source files), there are lots of things like this:

```
float f = (float)(6);
type_float tf = (type_float)(0); //type_float is a typedef of float xor double
```

In short, the author tried to make the RHS of assignments equal to the variable being assigned into.  The aim, I presume, was to coerce the compiler into making e.g. the `6` in the first example into `6.0f` so that no conversion overhead happens when that value is copied into the variable.

This would actually be useful for something like the second example, where the proper form of the literal (one of {`0.0f`,`0.0`}) isn't known/can be changed from a line far away.  However, I can see it being problematic if the literal is converted and stored into a temporary and then copied, instead of the conversion happening on copy.

Is this author onto something here?  Are all these literals actually being stored with the intended type?  Or is this just a massive waste of source file bits?  What is the best way to handle these sorts of cases in modern code?

Note: I believe this applies to both C and C++, so I have applied both tags.

Comment: There's no performance-related reason to put the cast on the right hand side. Pretty sure it's a stylistic choice.

Comment: Honestly, the casts in both of these are performance-irrelavent. The conversions will happen regardless (if possible). More than likely, the author put those in by mandate to squelch the plethora of warnings being issued . (i.e. loss of precision, etc).

Comment: Why wouldn't a production-quality compiler do such a simple thing for itself?

Comment: What makes you think that `float f = 6;` is actually slower than `float f = (float) 6;`? The conversion will always happen.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves If the conversion happens (i.e. the RHS casting doesn't lead to storing a converted value) I would actually expect the opposite, if there were to be any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a complete waste. No modern optimizing compiler will keep any track of intermediate values, but directly initialize with the final correct value. There is really no point in it, default conversion should always do the right thing, here. And yes this should apply to both, C and C++, and they shouldn't differ much in behavior.